# how to manage secrets of rails app while deploying application with chef habitat?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-habitat

I am looking for how can I manage my passwords/credentials while deploying my rails application with habitat. so that I don't have to commit my credentials into the version control.

Comment: The Rails 5.1+ way is that you actually commit the encrypted credentials to source control and the encryption key is left out. If you don't want to use it then you can use ENV vars.

Comment: https://kirillshevch.medium.com/encrypted-secrets-credentials-in-rails-6-rails-5-1-5-2-f470accd62fc

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering.  I got my answer.rails provide a way to store the credentials in encrypted form. and also habitat provides a way to store these credentials in ,toml file so that I do not have to commit that into git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after researching a lot I found a work around for the credentials.

so habitat credentials are stored in `.toml` file and you can use these credentials directly. now we need to send this toml file to server directly if we do not want to commit file.

or we can create databags.